# bootstrap 3 navbar branding colour

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using the bootstrap 3 navbar but cant for some reason change the brand text colour nor the dropdown triangles. i've tried a couple of things, but still no luck...

```
 .navbar .nav > .navbar-brand > a {
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    color:  #d6d6d6;
 }

.navbar-brand {
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    color:  #d6d6d6;
}

.navbar-brand a{
     text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
     color:  #d6d6d6;
}
```

Answer (score 36):

This is a specificity issue. The declaration contained in Bootstrap's CSS is more specific than yours. Please write your declaration this way:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
    color: #d6d6d6;
}
```

Simply using `.navbar-brand` is less specific and thus ignored. You may read a little bit about specificity [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

Comment: I was searching here and there for this particular answer. Can you also tell me how can I change the `hover` text color of `a` in `navbar-brand` class.

Comment: Bootstrap 3 defines this using the following CSS selector: `.navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover`, assuming the `navbar-brand` class is used directly on an `a` tag. If you place the `a` tag inside the element with class `navbar-brand`, the selector in your CSS will be `.navbar-default .navbar-brand a:hover`.

Answer (score 10):

In the bootstrap.css file:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
  color: #777777;
}
```

is where the Brand text color is set. I changed that to `color: #ff0000` and it successfully changed to red.
To change the color of the dropdown triangle,change values of color here

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .dropdown > a .caret {
  border-top-color: #777777;
  border-bottom-color: #777777;
}
```

For different colors on hover etc for the dropdown triangles:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .dropdown > a:hover .caret,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .dropdown > a:focus .caret {
  border-top-color: #333333;
  border-bottom-color: #333333;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a .caret,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover .caret,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus .caret {
  border-top-color: #ff0000;
  border-bottom-color: #ff0000;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

If your **navbar is black** you are using **navbar-inverse**, so these solutions won't work.

So in this case use:

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-brand {
    color: #d6d6d6;
}
```

Comment: Thanks buddy you save my day

Answer (score 3):

If your styles aren’t taking effect then it’s a specificity issue. Use the Web Inspector in Chrome or Safari and it will tell you what styles are in effect, and also the selector used to apply those styles.

Answer (score 1):

If other suggestions here do not work for you just add

!important

( None of them worked for me till I added !important )

```
.navbar-brand {
    color: #ffffff  !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<style> 
    /* Modify the background color */ 
      
    .navbar-custom { 
        background-color: lightgreen; 
    } 
    /* Modify brand and text color */ 
      
    .navbar-custom .navbar-brand, 
    .navbar-custom .navbar-text { 
        color: green; 
    } 
</style>
```

Comment: Please add a description what your code do. Just code alone is not as meaningful as a description of the written code.